# Javascript: string.Match() returning an array, not string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

```
var shouldbestring=myString.match(/(\d|π)(π|\(|sqrt)/);
```

shouldbestring is an array, not a string of two digits like I want.  I want to find a pair of a digit and pi, digit and (, pi and pi, etc

Comment: please add some use cases and the wanted result as well.

Comment: [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) always returns an array or null?!

Comment: ad hoc, use the first element of the returned array.

Comment: @Terminus, did you read that document at all? Because under the "RETURN VALUE"  heading it says "__An Array__ containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results;"

Comment: Well, try `.match(/(?:\d+|π)(?:π|\(|sqrt)/g)`. It would be much easier to help you if you provided an input string and expected output.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_match.asp stated that this function would return only the first match

Comment: It still returns it as an array. Of one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myString = "662π66";
var shouldbestring=myString.match(/(\d|π)(π|\(|sqrt)/);
console.log(shouldbestring[0]); // => 2π
```